# How to detect itunes store login cancel (cordova in app purchase)?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, in-app-purchase

I use In App Purchase 2 cordova plugin (https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase) to create in app purchases at an ionic application.

After refresh() Apple Store authentication pop up requires user id and password (it is like a login screen via an Alert). When cancel is clicked, I'd expect store.when(productId).cancelled() to be called.

The store.when(productId).cancelled() function is called when the product is registered and the purchase is cancelled during the transaction. However, if the "cancel" button is clicked during user authentication, there is no feedback from the API.

I also could not see an error thrown either. I might be doing something wrong but this is what I observe. I'd be grateful for you feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved after I understood that, the cancel button does raises the "cancelled", not on the store object, but on the product!

You need the refresh event first, to make sure the products have been loaded.

So, after store.refresh() :

```
var prod = store.get('myproductId');
if (prod) {
    prod.on('cancelled',function() {
        console.log('Cancel button clicked!');
    });
}
```

I was not able to get anything out of the cancel button up until now, but this did the trick :)